# Splitting a string at specific word

Tags: vb.net

hi guys I am using a stream reader to read a text file line by line to compare it to another text file.  The lines in the text file look something like this.

{ "Title": "My Title Here", "Description": "My Description Here", "Region": "My Region Here", "Url": "My Url Here", "Image": "My Image Here" };

I just want to split the string and return everything from the beginning of the line right up to "URL" including the quotes if possible ...the titles , descriptions and regions may be different lengths so I just want to split it at the key word "URL" and junk the rest of the string from there on so it looks more like this.

{ "Title": "My Title Here", "Description": "My Description Here", "Region": "My Region Here", "Url"

Can't seem to find the proper way to split this can someone please help me understand better...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by finding the index of "Url" and getting a substring to there.

```
    Dim input As String = "{ ""Title"": ""My Title Here"", ""Description"": ""My Description Here"", ""Region"": ""My Region Here"", ""Url"": ""My Url Here"", ""Image"": ""My Image Here"" };"
    Dim splitAt As String = """Url"""
    Dim index As Integer = input.IndexOf(splitAt)
    Dim output As String = input.Substring(0, index + splitAt.Length)
```

Comment: Instead of `Substring` you can also use `input.Remove(index)` (if you want to include the `splitAt` just append it)